# Preferences option to enable tab-key space inserting

Tags: feature-request

I would like to request enabling the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to insert `4 spaces`, just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> does, but for multiple levels of code. That would make it a lot easier to write small bits of code when needed, without having to press <kbd>Space</kbd> 4 times for each line of code for proper indentation.

I am aware there are also SO users who use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for navigation, to make it easier to submit the question by tabbing to the submit button, so I understand it is not added as a global feature. It would be nice to be able to enable it in the preferences though.

The features I'd like to request when this option is enabled would be:

- inserting `4 spaces` when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- inserting the same amount of whitespace as the current line when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  - unless the current line only contains whitespace
- removing `4 spaces` behind the caret when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- the same functionality as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> when pressing tab on highlighted areas, except indentation will only increase

  - same as above, but for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> where indentation will only decrease
- backspace will remove up to `4 spaces` when the caret is at the start of the line (same as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> when at the start of the line)
- and optionally:

  - pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> moves the caret in front of the first non-whitespace character on that line
  - pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> again will toggle between the actual start of the line, and the first non-whitespace character on the line

I hope I'm not the only one who would like to be able to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent code, like I do in editors. Also, since this is an opt-in feature, it wouldn't change anything about the current interface, so I think there is no harm in adding this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I wasn't aware that existed, but there is one difference: he's requesting it site-wide and I'm requesting it as a preferences option. Also, I don't really get it. What's the exact reason this is unnecessary? Copying it to another editor would be more effort than adding in a script once, and making that available for further use? Using a seperate editor seems like an unnecessary step, when tab indentation alone would make this editbox much easier to work with already.

Comment: I did notice the opt-in difference, that's why I chose a duplicate going along the "not needed and available elsewhere" axis instead of the "heresy! a11y!" one. My own opinion is that if you want "advanced" code formatting features, you can use an "advanced" editor (you have one open, as a programmer, right? :), then copy-paste. I'm also not a fan of extending the editor's `<textarea>` with that kind of features, especially if that means random selection and navigation issues (yes, I'm looking at you, jsFiddle).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi oh wow yes jsfiddle is a horrible editor. And of course I have an advanced text editor, but it just seems like an unnecessary extra step, for those who don't mind giving up tab-navigation. Usually tab indentation is all I really need when writing short bits of code.

Comment: thanks, that I dont have to ask the question. And what is wrong with asking for 'getting better'? the comments/answers here and the possible duplicate question sound like "why should we use something else than vi, its the best"

Comment: one more, I would even be happy if nothing happen if I press <TAB>, insead of finding myself anywhere